# How can I wait for 10 second without locking application UI in android

Tags: java, android, wait

I am stuck with a problem, I want to wait 10 second because I want my application to start the code below after that 10 sec but without stopping that person from clicking anything else in the application (*without* calling `Thread.sleep();`).

```
try {
    Log.v("msg", "WAIT CheckFrequencyRun");
    Thread.sleep(10000); // giving time to connect to wifi
    
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   //if no network
   if(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId()==-1){
    //stop wifi
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    Log.v("msg", "no connection");
    handler.postDelayed(this, checkInterval);
   }
   //else connection
   else{
    Log.v("msg", "connection");
    onDestroy();
   }
```

Comment: Have a look at these questions, they're looking quite similiar: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111905/how-do-you-have-the-code-pause-for-a-couple-of-seconds-in-android?rq=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630681/android-wait-the-main-thread-while-a-dialog-gets-input-in-a-separate-thread?rq=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640880/android-waiting-for-an-action?rq=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765034/wait-a-time-android?rq=1

Comment: postDelayed wont't lock your Ui but Thread.Sleep do. Remove Thread.Sleep and continue your work in your Runnable

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You never want to call `thread.sleep()` on the `UI` thread as it sounds like you have figured out. This freezes the `UI` and is always a bad thing to do. You can use a separate `Thread` and `postDelayed`

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay) shows how to do that as well as several other options

[Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

[TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

You can look at these and see which will work best for your particular situation

Answer (score 184):

You can use this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     // Actions to do after 10 seconds
    }
}, 10000);
```

For Stop the Handler, You can try this:
`handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`

Answer (score 3):

1with handler:

```
handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 10000);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 1) {
           //your code
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: what is the "TRIGGER" because android documentation ask for a int could not put string

Comment: I was wrong... this is id of your message. Try with 1

Answer (score 2):

do this on a new thread (seperate it from main thread)

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     }
}).run();
```