# How to delay iteration of loop in android studio

Tags: loops, android-studio

I want to know how I would add a delay in a for loop in android studio. I want to change the background of a button to a certain colour then change it back. Then I want to go on to the next iteration of the loop.

I tried using handlers and the count down timer but I am not getting the desired effect. The loop will not pause and wait.

This is what I essentially want to do:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int [] pattern = new int[score + 1];
for (int j = 0; j < score+1; j++) {
    pattern[j] = rand.nextInt(4);
//Here what I want is depending on the number, 
  I will change the colour and wait for a second then change it back all before the next iteration starts.
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237287/how-can-i-wait-for-10-second-without-locking-application-ui-in-android

Comment: If the problem is that the Timer or Thread.sleep will lock de UI, then you can make a service with an alarm with repeat or a thread.sleep and every X seconds  then fire a broadcast service  (inside the service) and finally listen this BROADCAST (in the MainActivity or the UI) and change your color here

Answer (score 0):

**Thread.sleep** ?

[Oracle - pausing execution with sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

Comment: Good to know, i'm too interested in this question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can archive with a TimerTask

```
TimerTask uploadCheckerTimerTask = new TimerTask(){ 
    public void run() { 
       System.out.println("timer_task");
     /*
         rest of your code (change the color here)
     */
    } 
}; 
Timer uploadCheckerTimer = new Timer(true); 
uploadCheckerTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(uploadCheckerTimerTask, 0, 60 * 1000);
```

The advantage of TimerTask is that is easy to impelent  and it already has the cancel() feature implemented.